# Using Like on a Parameter Variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Select Column1 From Table Where @Variable Like '%' + Column2 + '%'
```

Doesn't seem to work how I thought it would.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It should work. How do you think it would work?

Comment: Well, It doesn't work like `Where Column2 Like '%' + @Variable + '%'`

Comment: It's not a commutative function.  What is in your columns, variables, etc?

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work like" that? The two are different comparisons; naturally they won't necessarily have the same results. Show a specific example of where you get a match where you wouldn't expect one (or vice versa).

Comment: Ok, well since you know the issue, feel free to post your answer below. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(vague question)

Have you got Category and @Variable round the wrong way: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/630f5/3)

```
create table the_table 
(
  category varchar(10),
  [Date] datetime,
  Amount decimal(12, 2)
)

insert into the_table
values
( 'X', '2012-1-1', 10),
( 'X', '2012-1-3', 10),
( 'Y', '2012-1-3', 20),
( 'Y', '2012-1-5', 10)

declare @Variable varchar(10)
set @Variable = 'Y'

Select * 
From the_table 
--Where @Variable Like '%' + category + '%' 
Where category Like '%' + @Variable + '%'
```

Comment: Hmmm.. i suppose i can put the variable in a table first.. let me try.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of columns, you can use `case`:

```
where  case 
       when @Variable = 'col1' then col1 
       when @Variable = 'col2' then col2
       when @Variable = 'col3' then col3 
       ...
       end like '%' + Column2 + '%'
```

Another option is dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Select Column1 From Table Where ' + @Variable + 
    ' Like ''%'' + Column2 + ''%'''
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Variable` is not a value from a column, it's actually from a `param`.  So i guess i will update the question title.  Your 2nd example, no no no, please.