# Calling a procedure LIKE % SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I am creating a procedure which allows user to search product by name OR description with the LIKE operator

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Product(
    @name varchar(50),
    @description varchar(MAX) )

    AS
    SELECT  p.name,
            p."description"
    FROM Product p
    WHERE p.name LIKE @name OR p."description" LIKE @description
    GO
        EXECUTE usp_Product @kids or @toys for kids
```

I not sure where Im goin wrong, its the procedure code or executing the procedure.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: How about changing to LIKE '@description' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Like on a Parameter Variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152607/using-like-on-a-parameter-variable)

Comment: What do you mean by `@kids or @toys for kids`?

Comment: usr - the user car search a part of the name, eg %toy and every name that contains 'toy' will show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE p.name LIKE '%' + @name + '%' OR p.description LIKE '%' + @description + '%'
```

Comment: You may also want to escape special characters (like more %) in both variables.

Comment: thank you works nicely, when executing i added -                          EXECUTE usp_Product @name='toy' ,  @description='small'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Product(
@name varchar(50),
@description varchar(MAX) )

AS
SELECT Column_Name1,Column_Name2 FROM Table_Name WHERE Column_Name1 LIKE @name OR Column_Name2 LIKE @description
GO
```

and for executing stored procedure

```
EXECUTE usp_Product 'value1','value2'
```

Hope it may help