# SQL: like and variable couldn't show results

Tags: sql, sql-like, procedure

[image: Table Customer]

```
declare @Datos Varchar(80)
set @Datos='Llactas'
Select IdCliente,DNI,ApellidoPat,ApellidoMat,Nombre1,Nombre2,Direccion,Telefono 
    From Cliente Where ApellidoPat like '%@Datos%'
```

After run show that result

[image: Results]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Like on a Parameter Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152607/using-like-on-a-parameter-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
declare @Datos Varchar(80)
set @Datos='Llactas'
Select IdCliente,DNI,ApellidoPat,ApellidoMat,Nombre1,Nombre2,Direccion,Telefono 
    From Cliente Where ApellidoPat LIKE '%' + @Datos + '%'
```

Your

```
like '%@Datos%'
```

is trying to search "@Datos" in your table

Comment: now, show that error 
'The varchar and varchar data types are incompatible with the module operator.'

Comment: @JeofryLlactaCamposano  What is the type of ApellidoPat column?

Comment: @JeofryLlactaCamposano I think you missed something in your query. I've updated answer to include the whole query.